# Is it possible to overload the HTMLInputElement to provide it different locale?

Tags: javascript, html

`<input type="date">` for the displayed date uses the locale of the user's browser. I would like to force it use the locale that I choose. Is it possible to achieve that by overriding `HTMLInputElement`? If it is, how?

Comment: Have you tried specifying a different `lang` attribute?

Comment: @SebastianSimon It doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score -1):

As per [This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local)

```js
document.getElementById('meeting-time').timezone=document.getElementById('timezone').value;
```

```html
<label for="meeting-time">Choose a time for your appointment:</label>
<input type="hidden" id="timezone" name="timezone" value="-08:00">
<input type="datetime-local" id="meeting-time"
       name="meeting-time" value="2018-06-12T19:30"
       min="2018-06-07T00:00" max="2018-06-14T00:00">
```

Comment: This code does not appear in the linked page, and does not appear to attempt to change the locale of the input, as OP requested.